# Prime Number Spiral Clusters

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, clustering

I've written a program in Python that uses Turtle to draw out Prime Spirals. Essentially, it starts with a line of length 2, turns $\theta$ degrees then draws a line of length 3 and so on.

If I choose $\theta$ as the prime number itself (eg. I draw a line of length 2, then turn 2 degrees etc.), I get this interesting pattern of clusters:

[image]

[Prime Spiral Clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Sd9.png)

Is there a simple explanation for what these clusters represent?

Thanks!

**Edit** - Here are some new results from various tests:

[image: Natural Numbers Spiral]

This is running through the same program, except with the Naturals rather than Primes.

[image: Natural Numbers Spiral (Even Numbers)]

This is the result of it running through the even Natural numbers.

[image: Natural Numbers Spiral (Odd Numbers)]

And the same with odd Natural numbers.

[image: Every Third Natural Number Spiral]

This is every third Natural number.

[image: Every Third Prime Number Spiral]

Finally (and most interestingly) this is every third Prime number. Notice how chaotic it is compared to the rest!

Comment: What does it look like if you just use the natural numbers? Or just every third or fourth number? I suspect it will look similar. Angles in the interval $90^\circ - 180^\circ$ or in $270^\circ - 360^\circ$ will tend to make a cluster.

Comment: Thanks Jens!

I thought about it a bit more and yeah, just the natural rotation with larger and larger angles would tend to do that, and the "tails" would be caused by the smaller angles.

I'll run this program with the natural numbers to confirm this.

Comment: I've edited the post to include some more results. @Jens

Comment: What if you try it with, say, the squares? Or cubes? Or some other monotone sequence which is not arithmetic? Any polynomial of degree>1

Comment: The pattern seems to lose the clustering at polynomials of degree > 1. I tried it with both the naturals and the primes @Corey

Comment: @dibsonme Could you please include your Python program?